# Laravel How can I reject repeat the two column in database

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have table same like :

```
id | u_id | f_id
```

and I inserted some data like  :

```
id   = 1;
u_id = 5;
f_id = 8;
```

My question is how can I reject user insertion if he tries to insert the same data?

Comment: Put an unique constraint on your database table. That’ll soon flag it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new model is saved for the first time, the `creating` and `created` events will fire. If a model already existed in the database and the `save` method is called, the `updating` / `updated` events will fire. However, in both cases, the `saving` / `saved` events will fire.

For example, let's define an Eloquent event listener in a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers). Within our event listener, we will call the `isValid` method on the given model, and return `false` if the model is not valid. Returning `false` from an Eloquent event listener will cancel the `save` / `update` operation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\YourModel;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        YourModel::saving(function ($yourModel) 
        {
            if ( ! $yourModel->isValid() ) 
                return false;

        });
    }
}
```

In your model add `isValid()` function, inside this function you'll add your condition :

```
public function isValid()
{
    if( $this->u_id = 5 && $this->f_id == 8)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

**NOTE :** I guess that the `id` increment automatically.

Hope this helps.

**[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events)**